# Rails: After input, show difference

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Rails Newbie here.

I have a form where the user will input in a number of results in a table format and I want it to show the difference between the expected result and the input result as they move to the next input.

So I am looking for some after update trigger to trigger a js/ajax but I can't put it together.

I would like the difference between @range1_af_ecc.required and the actual input to be displayed in the column after the actual input.

```
<%= form_tag update_calibration_results_customer_asset_calibration_header_calibration_results_path(@customer.id,@asset.id,@calibration_header.id), method: :put do %>
    <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover table-sm table-responsive-sm word-break: break-all">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Sequence</th>
        <th>Actual</th>
        <th>Difference</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

<%  @range1_asfound_eccentricity.each  do |range1_af_ecc| %>
        <tr>
          <%= fields_for "range1_af_eccs[]", range1_af_ecc do |f| %> 
          <td><%= range1_af_ecc.sequence %></td>
          <td><%= f.number_field :actual, step: :any %></td>
          <td> DIFFERENCE TO GO HERE </td>
          <% end %>
        </tr>
      <% end %>     
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <%= submit_tag "Save" %>
 <% end %>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery `blur` event

`blur` event is called when an element loses focus

```
$(".class-of-input-where-user-enters-value").blur(function(){
  var input = $(this)
  var val = input.val()
  var row = input.parents('tr').eq(0)

  $.ajax({
    url: "/url",
    data: { value: val }

  }).done(function( response ) {
    row.find(".class-of-element-where-difference-goes").text(response)
  });

  // or you can run some JS code here to calculate difference
})
```

Comment: Thanks, can you point me in the right direction. How do I pull the contents of the rows 1'st `<td>` , I have tried `  $('table td:eq(0)')` but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `$("table tr").each(function(){ $(this).find("td:first").html() })`

Comment: When I use `var req = $("table tr").each(function(){ $(this).find("td:first").html() })` it returns `[object Object]` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: inside the `each` function you can access first `td`, `$(this).find("td:first")` gives you first `td` for each row in the table. If you want first td in the table then `$("table td:first")`.

Comment: If that is an `each` function (a loop?) then how would I then combine that with the previous `blur` function? If I put the `blur` function in the `each` function it won't trigger will it?